# How to train statsmodels.tsa.ARIMA model with multiple series

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, statsmodels

The usual way to fit an ARIMA model with the statsmodels python package is:

```
model  = statsmodels.tsa.ARMA(series, order=(2,2))
result = model.fit(trend='nc', disp=1)
```

however, i have multiple time series data to train with, say, from the same underlying process, how could i do that?

Comment: Have you found a solution to your problem? I have got exactly the same problem. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you say, multiple time series data, it is not clear if they are of the same type. There is no straightforward way to specify multiple series in ARMA model. However you could use the 'exog' optional variable to indicate the second series.

Please [refer](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA.html#statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARMA) for the actual definition of ARMA model.

```
model  = statsmodels.tsa.ARMA(endog = series1, exog=series2, order=(2,2))
```

Please [refer](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/endog_exog.html) for the explanation of the endog, exog variables.

Please see a working example of how this could be [implemented](http://barnesanalytics.com/analyzing-multivariate-time-series-using-arimax-in-python-with-statsmodels)

Comment: I understand that the question does not refer to exogenous variables. I think it refers to the case the time serie to predict is trucated, so instead of a long time series you have a set of shorter time series. Example: Imagine data each minute in a machine that is operating 9AM-5PM and then it is switched off, in this case the jump between afternoon and morning does not fit as a single time series since there isn't continuity.

Comment: This has nothing to do with exogenous variables. It clearly says from the same underlying process and your answer is incorrect. "exog" doesn't blong to the same process.

Answer (score 0):

**If your time series has cycles or periodics and is continious:**
Look at your data as a grid. The first dimension is your time variable and your second dimension is the time series number.

In order to incorporate this concept you need to make sure that each time series has the exact same initial state and it is continious.

Here is an example:
Assume power consumption in a city. You'll have 24hrs and 7 days cycles for sure in such scenarios.
You can devide the time series from 0 to N:

Sat(0) ... Fri(0)

Sat(1) ... Fri(1)

.
.
.

Sat(N) ... Fri(N)

Instead of forecasting the end of each time series you can fore cast the N+1 data set by fitting your ARMA model over all Sat(0)...Sat(N) and obtain Sat(N+1) etc.

Repeat this for each day of the week and you'll get the next value.

If your data does't have preiodicities this method or any other method will never work.

**If your time series doesn't have cycles or periodics and is segmented:**
You may want to use a statespace method to obtain the spectra of your dynamical system and make decsisions based on directions and magnitudes.